# How to drop malformed rows while reading csv with schema Spark?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

While I am using Spark DataSet to load a csv file. I prefer designating schema clearly. But I find there are a few rows not compliant with my schema. A column should be double, but some rows are non-numeric values.  Is it possible to filter all rows that are not compliant with my schema from DataSet easily?

```
val schema = StructType(StructField("col", DataTypes.DoubleType) :: Nil)
val ds = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", "\t").schema(schema).load("f.csv")
```

f.csv:

```
a
1.0
```

I prefer "a" can be filtered from my DataSet easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are reading a `CSV` file and want to drop the rows that do not match the schema. You can do this by adding the option `mode` as `DROPMALFORMED`

Input data

```
a,1.0
b,2.2
c,xyz
d,4.5
e,asfsdfsdf
f,3.1
```

Schema

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("key", StringType, false),
  StructField("value", DoubleType, false)
))
```

Reading a `csv` file with `schema` and `option` as

```
  val df = spark.read.schema(schema)
    .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
    .csv("/path to csv file ")
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+
|key  |value|
+-----+-----+
|hello|1.0  |
|hi   |2.2  |
|how  |3.1  |
|you  |4.5  |
+-----+-----+
```

You can get more details on [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) here

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Both of your answers are correct. So I set the first answer as accepted answer. But thank you both for your valuable answers!

Comment: How do I restore corrupt records if I want them for audit purpose. For eg, I want to create a new df with corrupt records.

Comment: Exactly, malformed records should be reported back to source system/vendor, its super basic function, do we have such feature in Spark?

Comment: One caveat is that you silently drop data from your input data

Answer (score 9):

`.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")` should do the work.

`mode` (default `PERMISSIVE`): allows a mode for dealing with corrupt records during parsing.

- `PERMISSIVE` : sets other fields to `null` when it meets a corrupted record, and puts the malformed string into a new field configured by `columnNameOfCorruptRecord`. When 
              a schema is set by user, it sets `null` for extra fields.
- `DROPMALFORMED` : ignores the whole corrupted records.
- `FAILFAST` : throws an exception when it meets corrupted records.

Comment: Isn't this same answer as other one ?

Comment: It will be better when result of CSV loader are actually 2 separate dataframe objects, one parsed, second corrupted.